# Django NameError at /HomeFeed/comments/testuser1-12 name 'slug' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I received this error from the code:
NameError at /HomeFeed/comments/testuser1-12
name 'slug' is not defined

Any idea why this is happening? Like which part is causing this problem too, how do i define slug without having a slug in the parameter of the function

Basically after posting the comment, i want to redirect back to the page of the post, which has a slug in the url.

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   body = models.TextField()
   date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'HomeFeed'
urlpatterns = [

    path('<slug>/detail/', detail_blog_view, name= "detail"),
]
```

views.py

```
class AddCommentView(DetailView, FormView):
    model = BlogPost # change model to post because your are commenting on POSTS not COMMENTS
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/add_comment.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.name = self.request.user
        comment.post = self.get_object()
        comment.save()
        return redirect(reverse("HomeFeed:detail", kwargs={'slug': slug }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to pass the value comment.post.slug:

```
return redirect(reverse("HomeFeed:detail", kwargs={'slug': comment.post.slug }))
```

the error is because slug is not a variable anywhere in your code

Comment: Yep, i tried that before and remember getting an attribute error saying it the view doesn't have slug

Comment: I just tried and got this: `No BlogPost matches the given query.`

Comment: maybe `comment.post.slug`

Comment: yup it worked! thanks...but could you explain how you got it? basically you are using the post as a foreign key to link to the slug field in the BlogPost model is it?

Comment: Glad i could help, as i understand it you couldnt get BlogPost in that context so you get it through the comment as it has a foreign key relation.

Comment: I was wondering because I have already specified my model = BlogPost, why do I need to still do it through comments

Comment: that just sets the model of the view to the model BlogPost, not an instance like you get from comment.BlogPost

Comment: thanks for the advice! Have a great day :)

Comment: Hi @Sirwill98 , is it true that to allow users to delete their comments, I will just need to add another function below `def form_valid(self, form): ` right? something like `@login_required
def delete_my_comment(request):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment)`

Comment: any idea how I can reference to that particular comment itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227335/discussion-between-sirwill98-and-kknam).

Comment: Hi man, I have replied you in the chat :)